# site giving error of Notice: Undefined index in following code

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting following error

```
Notice: Undefined index: criteriaparam_ex in /hermes/waloraweb018/b1876/as.vapwbcom/brindle.in/wbcom-ads-split-test/wp-content/plugins/wbcom-ads-split-test-master/wb-ad-sense.php on line 687
```

in following code lines

```
elseif( isset( $segment['criteriaparam_ex'] ) || ($segment['criteriaparam_ex']!="" ) && is_single( explode( ',', $segment['criteriaparam_ex'] ) ) )
```

Thanks

Comment: Should be - `isset( $segment['criteriaparam_ex'] ) && ($segment['criteriaparam_ex']!="" )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Condition should be:

```
elseif( isset( $segment['criteriaparam_ex'] ) && $segment['criteriaparam_ex'] !=""  && is_single( explode( ',', $segment['criteriaparam_ex'] ) ) )
```